# Can't call getElementsByTagName on loaded svg

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, svg

I'm loading an SVG using an XMLHttpRequest but I don't seem to be able to parse it.  Here's how I'm loading it

```
    var svgDoc;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "data/vectors.svg", true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                svgDoc = xhr.responseText;
                console.log(svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("svg"));
            } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
```

It's throwing  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.  When I try console.log(svgDoc.getElementsByTagName) I just get 'undefined'.  It's like I can't call any of the XML DOM methods on the SVG - despite the fact that SVG is just XML.  Why is this?

Comment: `svgDoc = xhr.responseText` means `svgDoc` is a _String_ and _Strings_ don't have a `getElementsByTagName` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, you are correct but it turns out there's a better solution.  Use a DOMParser to parse the string into a DOM object, then call DOM methods on it, like this:

```
 var svg;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "data/vectors.svg", true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                var svgStr = xhr.responseText;
                var parser = new DOMParser;
                var svgDoc = parser.parseFromString(svgStr, "text/xml");
                svg = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
                console.log(svg);
                var viewBox = (svg.getAttribute('viewBox').split(' '));
                offsetX = -parseInt(viewBox[2] / 2 + parseInt(viewBox[0]));
                offsetY = parseInt(viewBox[3] / 2) + parseInt(viewBox[1]);
                var sectionsXml = $(svg).find('g[id*="section"]');
                for (var i = 0; i < sectionsXml.length; i++){
                    var sect = new section(sectionsXml[i]);
                    sect.position.setX(offsetX);
                    sect.position.setY(offsetY);
                    scene.add(sect);
                }
            } else {
                console.error(xhr.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
        console.error(xhr.statusText);
    };
    xhr.send(null);
```

Sorted.

Answer (score 4):

If you use XMLHttpRequest to get the content of a remote HTML webpage, the responseText property is a string containing a "soup" of all the HTML tags, which can be hard to manipulate and analyze. There are three primary ways of analyzing this HTML soup string:

1. Use the XMLHttpRequest.responseXML property.
2. Inject the content into the body of a document fragment via fragment.body.innerHTML and traverse the DOM of the fragment.
3. RegExp can be used if you always know the content of the HTML responseText beforehand. You might want to remove line breaks, if you use RegExp to scan with regard to linebreaks. However, this method is a "last resort" since if the HTML code changes slightly, the method will likely fail.

*Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest*

---

In your case, the undefined error comes because the responseText is just a string (not a dom element).