# vanilla js equivalent to "Loading Page Fragments" via XMLHttpRequest by div id

Tags: javascript, jquery

For learning purposes, trying not to use jQuery to get remote content.

The following snippet works well. It fetches two divs and puts them in the current page.

It's fetching this raw gist:

```
<div class="remote" id='one'>one</div>
<div class="remote" id='two'>two</div>
```

```js
function remoteFetch() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var varUrl = 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/persianphilosopher/b0d4e948da801d09969b4ac6f5c0206d/raw/d139dd28e2cd5a73a4b38f489c8462c755c342c6/temp';

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {

        document.getElementById("here").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.open("GET", varUrl, true);
  xhr.send();
}
remoteFetch();
```

```html
<div id="here"></div>
```

**Question**: What I cannot figure out is the equivalent of the following jQuery bit:

```
$("#here").load("varUrl #one");
```

that would allow me to only fetch a div by its id.

The closest I found on SO is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27611985/5811465) but I failed to adapt it [here](https://codepen.io/persianphilosopher/pen/dKBPXZ?editors=1010) for my needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the code you are having a problem with here

Comment: I have. Where it says "here" with the link

Comment: No code should be in your actual question. Links to external sites should be for demonstration purposes only as links could rot, and users shouldn't have to go to a third party website just to see the code you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation in your codepen almost works, there's two issues which I've rectified in this fork:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VdJYVG?editors=1010

First issue was a typo on `svgDoc.getElementsById`, it should just be `svgDoc.getElementById`.
Second issue was a parsing issue in the DOMParser. You are passing in `text/xml` as the expected MIME-type while the content you want to parse is `text/html` .

Comment: Thank you for your answer that solves my silly troubles and for showing me the actual fix in the codepen. Much appreciated.